# duda sobre display table

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

hola chicos tengo el siguiente codigo:

```css
section #info_usuario.conversacion{
    border: 3px solid #2856b6;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion h3{
    padding: 15px 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion div{
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion a{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion a i{
    color:white;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion input+i{
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background: #2856b6;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion input{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0;
    border-color: #2856b6 !important;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion input,
section #info_usuario.conversacion input+i{
    height: 30px;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion div ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion div ul li{
    background: #2856b6;
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
section #info_usuario.conversacion div ul li.emisor{

}
```

```html
<section>
<div id="info_usuario" class="conversacion">
 <h3><a href=""><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-left"></i></a>PALADIOSsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</h3>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li class="emisor">Hola</li>
   <li>Hola que tal</li>
   <li class="emisor">Bien y tu?</li>
   <li>muy bien</li>
   <li class="emisor">que productos tienes?</li>
   <li>Tengo muchos productos relacionados con la alimentacion</li>
   <li>Patatas</li>
   <li>pollo</li>
   <li>pesados de diferentes tipos</li>
   <li class="emisor"> y para pedir</li>
   <li>en la web</li>
  </ul>
  
 </div>
 <input type="text" class="border_completo" placeholder="Mensaje..."><i class="zmdi zmdi-mail-send"></i>
</div>
</section>
```

bueno aun faltan muchos estilos por eso no se ejecuta bien pongo dos imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno como se aprecia en la imagen estoy haciendo un chat. Bueno mi duda es la siguiente seria correcto poner en un < li > display table para que los li ajusten el ancho segun el texto?

un saludo gracias.

Comment: perdonad me acabo dar de cuenta que no puse signos de puntuación en la pregunta :/ es que estoy en un ambiente ruidoso y cuesta concentrarse.

Comment: Podria ser otra opcion poner lo siguiente en < li>:
    display: block;
    width: max-content; ¿que tal es la compatibilidad con max-content en los navegadores?

Comment: No veo nada de malo en usar display table

Comment: semanticamente estaria bien??

Comment: la semántica es para el html, los estilos son solo apariencia, que algo tenga la apariencia de una tabla no significa que se convierta en una tabla, si era una lista semánticamente lo seguirá siendo.

Comment: ok, es que lo que procuro es que sea loas correcto posible, sin dejar de lado el apartado visual y vomo hay multiples opciones pues siempre me planteo estas dudas